# How to install man pages for C standard library functions in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, manpages

In my university, I can do such things as:

- man strlen
- man strcpy
- man msgget
- man msgctl

and a nice manual page appears.  On my PC I get

```
$ man strcat
No manual entry for strcat
```

Any help on how to get those documentation pages into my computer?

Comment: Nowadays is easier, because the average computer is connected to the Internet. You can type "man foo" directly into google :-)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Install the `manpages-dev` and `manpages-posix-dev` (thanks ChristopheD) packages. You should be able to find them in synaptic, or type

```
apt-get install manpages-dev
apt-get install manpages-posix-dev
```

at the command line.

Comment: Or `apt-get install manpages-dev manpages-posix-dev`. Not doing thing the most efficient way drives my programmer OCD nuts. Sorry.

Comment: On voidlinux, its the packages `man-pages-devel` and `man-pages-posix`.

Comment: What is `manpages-posix-dev`?

Comment: worked perfectly for me.  I used to have all those manpages at hand.  I have updated my OS version several times and never lost the man pages before.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai The `manpages-posix-dev` contains things like `man 3 accept` or `man 3 connect` which are handy if you are doing socket programming and what not. I am assuming that these are all of the system calls, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 10):

For Fedora, you can install it using `yum`:

```
yum install man-pages libstdc++-docs
```

Comment: This answer is correct and should not have been voted down, since OP did not mention any distro.

Comment: This also helped me for red hat. Thank you.

Comment: @SoumyadipDM Looking at the edit history of the question shows the original title was "how to install man pages for C standard library functions in **Ubuntu**?" In fact, the title has always had Ubuntu in it.

Answer (score 4):

You may find glibc-doc package useful as well. From http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/glibc-doc:

> Contains The GNU C Library Reference
>   manual in info and html format as well
>   as the man pages for libpthread
>   functions and the complete GNU C
>   Library ChangeLog.

Answer (score 3):

On a ubuntu system they are in the packages

```
manpages-posix-dev (headers)
manpages-dev (functions)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu + others; You can also do a search in aptitude. I.e:

```
:~$ aptitude search manpages
i   asr-manpages          - alt.sysadmin.recovery manual pages
i   csound-manpages       - manual pages for csound
i   erlang-manpages       - Erlang/OTP manual pages
i   freebsd-manpages      - Manual pages for a GNU/kFreeBSD system
i   funny-manpages        - more funny manpages
i   gmt-manpages          - Manpages for the Generic Mapping Tools
i   manpages              - Manual pages about using a GNU/Linux system
p   manpages-cs           - Czech version of the manual pages
p   manpages-de           - German manpages
p   manpages-de-dev       - German development manpages
i   manpages-dev          - Manual pages about using GNU/Linux for development
p   manpages-es           - Spanish man pages
p   manpages-es-extra     - Spanish extra manpages
p   manpages-fr           - French version of the manual pages about using GNU/Linux
p   manpages-fr-dev       - French version of the development manual pages
...
```

Where "i" mean the package is installed and "p" means purged/not installed.

```
~$ man aptitude
```

And then i.e:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install manpages-es-extra
```

Other systems has similar functions.

Answer (score 1):

It always annoys me about ubuntu that I have to go searching around for the man pages and info pages to load. Fedora installs docs by default. At least they seem to be looking at it: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/10240/